# DragToScroll React, КАК?

Tags: html, css, reactjs

есть вот такой дизайн[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

мне нужно DragToScroll вот эту полосу хэштегов(представим, что их там много и они скрылись, как только зашли за красную линию)

контейнер Hashtags - вмещает в себе эти хэштеги

```
<div className='Hashtags' >
<HashTag HashTag='SEO' />
</div>
```

css `div Hasgtags`

```
.Hashtags{
    display: flex;
    width: 70%;

    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

файл Hashtag

```
import React from 'react'

import './HashTag.css';

function CheckIsHasTag(props){
        if(props.hashtag.includes('#')){
            return(
                <p className='Hashtag'>{props.hashtag}</p>
            )
        }
        else if(!props.hashtag.includes('#')){
            return(
                <p className='Hashtag'>#{props.hashtag}</p>
            )
        }
}

class HashTag extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            hashtag: props.HashTag
        };
    }


    render(){
        return (
                <CheckIsHasTag hashtag={this.state.hashtag}/>
        )
    }
}

export default HashTag
```

Comment: пробовали готовые решения - https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-indiana-drag-scroll ?

Comment: Только что попробывал и как я понял я использую версию  react@"^18.1.0", а drag scroll поддерживает только: react@"^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0 || ^17.0.0". Есть какие то варианты ?

Comment: и что именно тут не работает ? https://codesandbox.io/s/immutable-field-8m9t4p?file=/src/App.js

Comment: В плане я не могу установить этот пакет, мне выбивает куча ERROR с вот таким текстом [https://codesandbox.io/embed/friendly-vaughan-pq0svm?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark]

Не знал как ещё показать его

Comment: я тут ещё добавил логи https://codesandbox.io/embed/friendly-vaughan-pq0svm?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: держи в ответе.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно установить готовую версию [react-indiana-drag-scroll](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-indiana-drag-scroll). При установки на `React 18 and npm >= 7` могут быть проблемы, с конфликтом peerDependencies ([подробнее тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66020820/npm-when-to-use-force-and-legacy-peer-deps)). Поэтому установить можно, с один из параметров, например: `npm i react-indiana-drag-scroll --legacy-peer-deps`

```
<div className="App">
  <ScrollContainer className="scroll-container">
    <div className='item'>item</div>
    <div className='item'>item</div>
    <div className='item'>item</div>
    <div className='item'>item</div>
    <div className='item'>item</div>
    <div className='item'>item</div>
    <div className='item'>item</div>
    <div className='item'>item</div>
    <div className='item'>item</div>
  </ScrollContainer>
</div>
/** styles */
.scroll-container {
  width: 400px;
  display: flex;
}

.item {
  padding: 5px 15px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  background-color: darkorange;
  margin: 4px 10px;
}
```

Comment: Есть! Сработало! Большое спасибо, хотя те нервы уже не вернуть